# Objective-c emulating HTML 5 File API readAsBinaryString()

Tags: objective-c

Using the HTML5 File API I can get the Binary String representation of a file using FileReader.readAsBinaryString(). For an image this might return: ""ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿáExifMM*bj(1r2i¤ÐHHAdobe Photoshop CS Windows2006:07:12 15:24:47 ÿÿ...". Using Objective-C, I'm trying to get the same representation of a file.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
unsigned char *aBuffer = malloc([data length]);
[data getBytes: aBuffer length:[data length]];
return [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:aBuffer length:[data length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

The above has two issues (at least), there is a memory leak and the output is only 'ÿØÿà'. How do I get the full string and avoid a memory leak?

Edit when I do this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
return [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

I get the exact same output.

WebKit does the following (in C++):

```
 m_stringResult = String(static_cast<const char*>(m_rawData->data()), m_bytesLoaded);
```

That is within FileReaderLoader.cpp, line 252. It is within WebCore, which is within WebKit.

Comment: Why not try `return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`? Saves messing about with buffers.

Comment: Abizern, when I do that I still get 'ÿØÿà' as output. I'm not sure what's happening to the rest. Actually, when I copy what you have above I get null. But when I change the encoding to NSASCII... I just those 4 chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the memory leak: have you heard of -autorelease?

```
return [[[NSString alloc] initWith...] autorelease];
```

For the core problem:

NSString assumes to get a C string as its "bytes" parameter. So it will only get the file contents up to a 0x00 byte, which it interprets as a 'terminating NUL' character.
By the way, the correct method to do it is not forcing a poor NSString instance to initialize itself with invalid (non-ASCII, non-string!) garbage. You'd better use NSData's -bytes method to get a byte array. You can even access its individual bytes using something like this:

```
int index = [data lenght] - 1;
char byteAtIndex = ((char *)[data bytes])[index];
```

Comment: Ok, but in the end I need an NSString representation of the binary data. So how do I go from NSData to NSString? The only method within NSData that does this is description which is the hex representation...

Comment: You can't do that. It's really a design problem in your program if you can't do the job without it.

Comment: If WebKit can do it, why can't I?

Comment: What do you mean by 'WebKit can do it?'

Comment: In the original question I state that the File API (WebKit) can output the 'BinaryString' representation of a file. The output above matches the first 4 characters of what WebKit gives me. How does WebKit get the whole file and convert it to a string?

Comment: If you exactly know how WebKit does it, why not mimic it? string::string *the_string = string::string([data bytes], [data length]);

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do!

Comment: Then what's the problem? You don't want to use C++, or what?

Comment: =) I'm not familiar with C++,and the project is already Objective C.

Comment: You can intermix Objective-C and C++. If you're not familiar with C++, just paste my line from above ;) http://www.macresearch.org/objective_c_for_objective_c_programmers